# RabbitMQ is running still getting connection refused Connect Exception

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have installed rabbit MQ 3.8.3 on windows 10 and I can see it is running as windows services.
When I try to access http://localhost:15672/ it is unreachable.

I have enabled the rabbit MQ management plugin in sbin directory
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

But still, http://localhost:15672/ is unreachable.

Getting the following error in java service :

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have also run the command to see if anything is running on port 5672:

Command :  `netstat -ano | find "5672"`

Response : `TCP    0.0.0.0:25672          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2900`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like Rabbit services are running. Check in task manager for the processes?

Comment: i can see it computer management -> service and applications @PradiptaSarma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop rabbitmq
2. Create the RABBITMQ_BASE environment variable set its value to full
       path of rabbit mq server. (eg. C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server)
3. Restart the rabbit mq and make sure the rabbit mq plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The management UI can be accessed using a Web browser at http://{node-hostname}:15672/

The management plugin is included in the RabbitMQ distribution. Like any other plugin, it must be enabled before it can be used.

please refer below URL:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did the following steps :

Open a command prompt and type

```bash
CD C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.12.7\sbin
```

Then

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Now you should access it using http://localhost:15672/.